# How to update Vue nested data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

If I have data like so in Vue JS 2:

```
data : {
  newBus: {
    name: '',
    hours: {
      sunday: '',
    }
  }
}
```

How do I write to this location? I'm using the following:

`<input v-model="newBus.hours.sunday" type="text" placeholder="Sunday">`

But I get the error:

> vue.js:1453 TypeError: Cannot read property 'sunday' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That works fine. Your problem isn't in what you have included here.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    newBus: {
      name: '',
      hours: {
        sunday: '9-5',
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="newBus.hours.sunday" type="text" placeholder="Sunday">
</div>
```

Comment: Oops, you are correct. I have identified another issue but that does technically answer the question I asked haha. Thanks!

Comment: One of the benefits of creating a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is that you catch these red herrings.